# OpenId did not link to the correct profile on SEDE

Tags: support, openid, data-explorer

I just logged into the Data Explorer after a long time of not using it, with my normal openid.  I was created as a [new user](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/5373), when I can still see that my [original user](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/1412) is obviously still around.

Can I get a merge?

Also is this a bug, or did I not set up something right the first go around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merged this today, and a bunch of other users. Google mucked around with the openid tokens at the time and really messed up stuff for data.se.

Comment: Isn't OpenID *fun!?*

Comment: Cool, waffles is playing in SEDE, look at those [tag:status-completed] fly! I'm guessing that this correction is related to the fact that when I just went to SEDE, I saw a logout link but no profile link? (Fixed by logging out and logging back in again).